# Load data infile on a variable having a csv file

Tags: java, mysql, database, csv, prepared-statement

I need to populate 500 CSV files, each having 400-500 ROWS. But the CSV files are available online as `example.com/report.csv.gz`. So each of the csv files are compressed, and is a connection to a URL.

So, I'm using

`in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream())));`

to first decompress to get the CSV data, then I'm using `PreparedStatement` on each line to pouplate mySQL database. But it is taking a long time( Around 20 seconds for just 14 CSV ).

So, as suggested by a couple of other posts on faster populating methods, I want to use LOAD DATA INFILE.

Can someone help me with the code? Because LOAD DATA INFILE is for file, and I have a variable that's storing all the CSV data.  Any other suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){

    html+=inputLine; // Variable to store the CSV <---                

    String[] rowItems = inputLine.split(",");
    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO tableX"
                        + "(a, b, c, d, e, F, g, h, i, j, k, l, m) VALUES"
                        + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";                        
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rowItems.length; i++){
        preparedStatement.setString(i+1, rowItems[i]);
    }                       
    preparedStatement .executeUpdate(); 

}
```

So, I was wondering if there way a way to populate using `html` variable that I'm using to store CSV for each link.

Comment: Have you evaluated which part of the code is taking the most part of the time? You should do this using a profiler before trying to optimize non-relevant code.

Comment: Without the part the uses `PreparedStatement` to pouplate the database, it takes only 2-3 seconds to read through the csv files(14 files).

Comment: Not stated in your code, but how are you retrieving the connection, using a Database Connection Pool or using `Driver.getConnection`?

Comment: I'm using `Driver.getConnection`. 
`Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL+databaseName,userName,password);`

Comment: Then that's your bottleneck. This operation will open a new connection everytime. Instead, using a Database Connection Pool the connections will be *sleeping* until you tell the pool to *retrieve* a connection, then the pool will *wake* a connection and give it to you (this is **hell faster** than reopening a connection on every iteration).

Comment: Also, to improve some performance, you can use `updateBatch` as stated in IvanNik answer, but you will still have the main performance bottleneck based on the connection retrieval stated before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please provide some resources to learn about this?

Comment: It will depend. Is your application standalone (console, desktop) or is it deployed on an application server?

Comment: I'm running this on Tomcat using Servlet

Comment: Refer to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll keep this question open, to see if anybody has other suggestions as well. Thanks

Comment: Also don't forget to **always** close the resouces i.e. calling `Connection#close`.

Answer (score 1):

you should to use Update with Batching: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm#CHDCCEHD

Comment: Note from comments, this will reduce some overhead but won't fix the main performance problem.